# Java HttpServer read timeout with subsequent requests from same app too close each other

Tags: java, http, server, timeout, httpserver

I'm going crazy due to an issue with java **HttpServer**.
I create my server with contexts, etc and then from client app I use **URLConnection** with **InputStream** to connect to the server.

The problem is that very often (without an apparent logic) the client gets read timeout when it performs more subsequent requests too close each other. 
To avoid that I must put a **sleep(5000)** (why 5000? because under 5000 it still gives timeout) from a connection and the next one.

I already tried to use Executors (with both **Executors.newCachedThreadPool()** and **Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)**, but nothing.

Another strange thing using 2 clients:

1. Client 1: first request = ok
2. Client 2: first request = ok
3. WAIT FEW SECONDS
4. Client 1: second request = ok
5. Client 1: third request = freeze, it keeps trying (see code below), and then gives timeout
6. Client 2: second request = ok (while client 1 is still trying and gets timeout)

So.. The problem seems to be related to the specific client instance

Here some code

**SERVER**

```
try {
        cryptex = new ServerCryptex();
        final Executor multi = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8888), 50);

        addContexts();

        server.setExecutor(multi);
        server.start();


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyHttpServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The contexts are added with

```
server.createContext("/empty", new HttpHandler_Empty(this));
```

etc

**CLIENT**

This is the function that performs the request

```
 public byte[] performRequest(HashMap<String, String> params, String host, int port, String handler, boolean isConnectionEncrypted) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    URL url = composeUrl(params, host, port, handler, isConnectionEncrypted);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(300);
    con.setReadTimeout(7000);
    InputStream is = null;

    **NO PROBLEM UNTIL HERE**

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println("open the stream, try #" + i);

            **TIMEOUT ON THE NEXT LINE**

            is = con.getInputStream();
            break;
        } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ex) {

            **I THOUGHT TO USE THIS WAY TO TRY 5 TIMES THE CONNECTION BEFORE GIVING ERROR TO THE USER, BUT NOTHING. **

            sleep(500);
            if (i == 4) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    String reply = readReply(is);
    System.out.println("read reply:" + reply);
    if (isConnectionEncrypted) {
        return cryptex.decrypt(reply);
    } else {
        return reply.getBytes();
    }

}
```

The real code (without the 5 tries code)

```
public byte[] performRequest(HashMap<String, String> params, String host, int port, String handler, boolean isConnectionEncrypted) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    URL url = composeUrl(params, host, port, handler, isConnectionEncrypted);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(300);
    con.setReadTimeout(2000);

    System.out.println("open the stream");
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

    String reply = readReply(is);
    System.out.println("risposta letta:" + reply);
    if (isConnectionEncrypted) {
        return cryptex.decrypt(reply);
    } else {
        return reply.getBytes();
    }

}
```

And the error

```
giu 12, 2018 10:58:01 PM gui.Client_GUI aggiornaUdg
GRAVE: null 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at net.ClientConnector.performRequest(ClientConnector.java:96)
at net.ClientConnector.checkKey(ClientConnector.java:43)
at net.Client.getUDG(Client.java:56)
at gui.Client_GUI.aggiornaUdg(Client_GUI.java:2407)
at gui.Client_GUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(Client_GUI.java:1917)
at gui.Client_GUI.access$000(Client_GUI.java:53)
at gui.Client_GUI$1.actionPerformed(Client_GUI.java:390)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What could it be? Have you got any suggestion to avoid this issue?
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason of the issue.. But I resolved using [Apache Java HTTP Client Library](https://hc.apache.org)

Here the code

```
public byte[] performRequest(HashMap<String, String> params, String host, int port, String handler, boolean isConnectionEncrypted) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    URL url = composeUrl(params, host, port, handler, isConnectionEncrypted);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());

    // add request header
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String t = "";
    String s = rd.readLine();
    while (s != null) {
        t = t + s;
        s = rd.readLine();
    }

    System.out.println("risposta letta:" + t);
    if (isConnectionEncrypted) {
        return cryptex.decrypt(t);
    } else {
        return t.getBytes();
    }
}
```